# How to set decimals in Pandas dataframe equal to anothet column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

in a Pandas dataframe I have some columns that could need 2 or 4 or 5 decimals depending on how many decimals other columns have.
i.e. Indexes usually have 2 decimals but forexpairs do have more,

If I calculate a value (i.e. use an indicator) I want that value to be rounded to the same number of decimals as the OHLC values.

I know by df.round(decimals=2) you can set the rounding for a particular column but I don't know how to retrieve that specification in order to use it for another column.

Is there a function or variable I can get or should I look for the position of a separator in a row in a cclumn to findout?

The picture below contains columns OHLC having 2 decimals followed by various columns with4,,6 decimals. If want all those columns to have 2 decimals as well.
But Is also will have columns with 0 or 1 decimal in the future.
In case of forxpairs (EURUSD) OHLC will have more than 2 decimals. In that case all the columns should have that amount of decimalss as well.

[image]

Comment: Please post sample of your data and desired output

Comment: DO NOT round decimals before doing computations.  That only leads to accumulating round-off errors.  Do your computations with the full precision, and limit the decimals when you DISPLAY the data.  Human beings are the only ones who care about the number of decimals.

Comment: Or multiply by a different power of 10 for each column/group and compute everything as integers

Answer (score 0):

You can take any one value from OHLC column convert it into string and split the value by '.'. Take the length of the latter part and that would be your decimal precision. You can then use this precision for other columns as well.

Sample code:

```
len(str(value).split('.')[-1])
```